# Python Selenium can't click on element: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click into a link of a simple menu, but when I try, selenium crashes and show: `get_balance -> error -> Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

I've tried several solutions described in Stackoverflow, for example, waiting a few seconds or finding the element by full xpath, but Selenium is still unavailable to click the link.

This is currently my code:

```
# self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5) # Instance attribute used below
# This is also not working:
# self.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div[1]/ul/li[1]'))).click()

menu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
menu.click()
```

This is the HTML that I get when I use the inspect element tool.
[image: HTML of menu]

I also tried with `execute_command` with JS Path, but I have the same result.

Sorry my bad english, If you don't understand something I can reformulate, or feel free to edit my question.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `xpath` is brittle. there are others way such as `link_text`

try this :

```
time.sleep(5)
self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Posic').click()
```

Comment: I'm having the same error with `find_element_by_partial_link_text`: `error -> Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Comment: Can you update your question with exact error stack trace and at what line it occurs.